# What would happen if a zombie bit a pregnant woman?

Tags: biology, science-in-society, zombies, viruses

Let's say during a zombie apocalypse or outbreak a young pregnant woman was bit by a zombie ether on the arm,leg, or shoulder and the virus spread to the child, what would realistically happen?

To me I like to think would happen is,

1. Both the mother and child die and turn to zombies.
2. The mother dies but not before giving birth to the child who has a immunity to the virus given the fact the Kid  expose to it during his/hers development cycle.

3.The mother dies but not before giving birth to the child who becomes a zombie human hybrid.

Comment: Note that a virus does not unavoidable spread to an embryo. Mother and child have dissociated blood circulations and exchange nutrients through a membrane. The child could be born healthy without an infect.

Comment: It seems like you have already come up with three possible answers to your own question.

Comment: Zombies do not exist, you need to decide how work .

Comment: @Vincent the OP is talking about a virus, thus an answer can take the angle of virology.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T that's still pretty broad

Comment: @Vincent that can be argued about. But at least there's a definition how zombiism is passed on. The OP could make the question *better* by providing any information on what happens after contracting the virus. But that's it. The question, as of now though, could probably be answered by looking into how viruses are exchanged between mother and child during pregnancy and using that data.

Comment: @Andrew while it is in your rights to accept an answer as soon as you like to it is common consensus on here to wait at least 24 hours. This is to give people time to discover the question and try themselves at it should they wish so - which in turn provides better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to answer this question is to put it in the context of what happens when a pregnant woman (whose immunity is usually considered low) is infected with any of a variety of known viruses. Here are few known scenarios:

**HIV**: Some risk of transmission, not 100%. Child is not immune to HIV. Mother will progress to AIDS eventually, in the absence of treatment. Child will too, if the virus was transmitted.

**Zika**: Mother may be asymptomatic and not know she is ill. Baby has a hugely elevated risk of microcephaly and learning disability, even though Zika is mild in adults. **The disease is worse for the baby than the adult.**

**Rubella**: Causes German measles in mother (I believe penetrance is 100%) and high risk that the baby will miscarry, be still born, or have birth defects. **The disease is worse for the baby than the adult.**

**Influenze**: Risks to fetuses are less but still include birth defects, especially if the mother has a high fever.

**Ebola**: The mother has a very high chance of dying, and so the baby has a high chance of not making it to term. Also, Ebola is so devastating the pregnancy will likely terminate even if the mother survives.

**Herpes viruses** (including CMV): Usually more dangerous to fetus than mother. **The disease is worse for the baby than the adult.**

I am not aware of a single virus that is *less* threatening to the fetus than to the mother, although some viruses are simply not a concern during pregnancy.

More relevantly, some viruses are not 100% transmitted to the fetus, although as a rule of thumb most things that causes a drastic effect on the mother do appear to have a high transmission to the fetus.

So, the **answer to your question,** most realistically, is that the baby will almost always be as badly affected as the mother, and oftentimes worse, with new symptoms that an adult wouldn't have. (e.g. Zika virus).

Some babies may escape without being infected if transmission is not 100%, and the stage of pregnancy (trimester) will impact how severely the baby will be affected. Babies are not typically immunized by this sort of challenge.

Here is [one example of a horrific disease that was not transmitted to the baby](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4818921/). The mother died perinatally.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "realistic" answer to zombie situations.  However, if we ignore that word, we can look at what might happen with a virus.  If the virus is fatal, which this one appears to be, there is a very good chance that the child will be spontaneously aborted (stillborn, if they're far enough along).

To have your immunity scenario occur, the virus would have to be stymmed by something about the child being too young.  Perhaps the cells the virus needs to reproduce simply aren't present in a fetus.  In general, if a virus is as dangerous as it would need to be to create a zombie, it's not going to be fooled by the fact that the fetus is still young, giving it some immunity.  However, if the virus can't get a foothold because of {insert biology here, such as missing cells to infect}, an immunity might work out.

As for zombie-human hybrids, that is 100% based on your own story.  If you want zombie-human hybrids, have zombie-human hybrids.  Of course, the consequence of having them is having to define what a zombie-human hybrid *is*, and how it behaves, but that's your world to build!